# Thinking Shpinx only executes one query in rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, thinking-sphinx

I'd like to perform two search queries using thinking sqhinx in a ruby on rails controller. 
TS is all set up and working. Now for some weird reason, only one of two queries is executed.

Code in my controller looks like this:

```
    @s1 = Sample.search(:conditions => {:name=>@name})
    @s2 = Sample.search(:conditions => {:comment=>@comment})
```

Now according to the rails console, only the first is executed (and returning the expected results btw.).

My sample.rb model looks like

```
...    
define_index do
        indexes :name
        indexes :comment
end
...
```

Using Thinking Sphinx 2.0.10, Rails 3.1.1, PostgrSQL 8.4

Comment: did u try running the search individually in the console, does both give you an output

Comment: It may do the request just on time, when you try to actually access the content of `@s1` and `@s2` ... are you accessing these variables somewhere?

Comment: @ross: yes, individually they both work. actually, at one point they both were executed. then I changed some things (and back again) and now they don't...

Comment: @anthony: yes, both vars are accessed. a line later I want to do someting like @s=(@s1+@s2).uniq